# Loose Mime-type when upload image data using file_put_content

Tags: php

```
$data = base64_decode($_POST['data']);

if (!is_dir(UPLOAD_PATH)) {
    return 'Error: Upload path does not exist';
}

if (!file_put_contents(UPLOAD_PATH.$name, $data)) {

    return 'Error while writing data, please check your server config';

}else return true;
```

When i upload photo using above code then it Looses Mime-type (content-type) header response. You can see i've used function like this.

Comment: what is the type of file you are trying to upload here?

Comment: You can see
1) http://prntscr.com/l4vjul (After upload)
2) http://prntscr.com/l4vj9x (Original)

Comment: @MangeshSathe JPEG/JPG/PNG/GIF

Comment: you have to save entire encoded data into db or in a variable and while displaying image go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: encoded string should have data:image/png;base64, as part of the encoded data

Answer (score 1):

You can configure mimetype for file_put_contents using a stream context as follow the documentation:

int file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php